# When I put my password Environment Variables it won't work

Tags: next.js

My code works as below in my localhost. What I'm trying to do is put my password in my .envlocal but it won't work.

**working code**

```
export default function (req, res) {

    let nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      port: 465,
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
         auth: {
              user: 'myEmail@gmail.com',
               pass: 'password123',
           },
      secure: true,
    });

    const mailData = {
        from: 'keshibatmail@gmail.com',
        to: 'kensukeshibata@gmail.com',
        subject: `Message From ${req.body.name}`,
        text: req.body.message + " | Sent from: " + req.body.email,
        html: `<div>${req.body.message}</div><p>Sent from: ${req.body.email}</p>`
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailData, function (err, info) {
        if(err)
          console.log(err)
        else
          console.log(info);
    })

    console.log(req.body)
    res.send('success')
  }
```

**What I tried.**
My next.js is

> "next": "10.x"

,
So I should be able to use this since my next.js is higher than 9.4 https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables

I made .env.local file
`NEXT_PUBLIC_PASSWORD=password123`

then `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PASSWORD`

I tried without NEXT_PUBLIC_ as well.

I get this error.
response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

```
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      port: 465,
      host: "smtp.gmail.com",
         auth: {
              user: myEmail@gmail.com,
               pass: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PASSWORD,
           },
      secure: true,
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a typo or not, but in your working version you have the `user` email address wrapped in quotes, but in your problematic code it's missing the quotes. So maybe that's the problem? Also, try logging `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PASSWORD` to the console to see if it has the value you're expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this can help others.

First, you are using an API, because I read:

```
export default function (req, res) {
```

That means that the code you are showing is running in the server.

In that case, you don't need to use `NEXT_PUBLIC_` in the `env` var.

That is only need when you want the vars to be exposed in the browser. And in this case, this code is not running in the browser but in the server. Also, it is important that vars like passwords are not exposed in the browser because all people will see them.

And the other thing, I was having similar problems using the password for email in the `.env.local` file. I realized that I let a space in the sentence at the end.

I have `MAIL_PASS="xxx"`  with a space left in the end of the line.

I deleted the space, and the correct password was taken.